# Nginx Proxy under multiple locations multiple server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to setup Nginx Proxy for multiple application from multiple servers.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name 192.168.2.28;
        ssl on;

   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;


  location /dashboard/ {
         proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
                    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
                    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
                    port_in_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.250/;
    }
}
```

While running https://192.168.2.28/dashboard in browser I am getting the only root files i.e /favicon.png But inside subfolders like js/css  are not resolving with location.

How to resolve domain with location with inside directories. I also attached the screenshot. Please, anyone, check and resolve.

[Nginx SSL proxy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hu9t.png)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem correctly, you want nginx to answer requests for static files directly while proxying everything else to your django-backend.

try adding this to your server config:

```
location /static/ {
     alias       /path/to/static/directory/;
}
```

as described in detail [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

in case you want a location to represent a remote path,
nginx can `rewrite` requests like so:

```
location ~ /static/ {
    rewrite (.*)/(.*) http://external.tld/static/$2; 
}
```

more on that option [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need static files from external websites. http://192.168.1.250/static/css/main.9c622a2d.css to proxy server => http://192.168.2.28/dashboard/static/css/main.9c622a2d.css

Comment: thanks for clarifying. answer is updated. one small thing: it's considered bad practice to use real IPs, even internal ones